# External direct product realized as an internal direct product. What is the meaning of "realize"? Is my isomorphism correct?

Tags: group-isomorphism, direct-product

I don't quite understand this sentence: "Every external direct product is naturally realized as an internal direct product."

Does "realize" mean that $H\times K$ is equal to $H+K$ (where $H,K$ are groups and `+` between groups means internal product) ? Or does it mean $H\times K$ is isomorphic to $H+K$ ?

I tried to prove these two are isomorphic, with the isomorphism $\phi: H\times K \rightarrow H+K$ such that $\phi: X \mapsto \pi_1 (X) \cdot \pi_2 (X)$ where $\pi_1 , \pi_2 $ are the projections from $H\times K$ to $H$ and $K$ respectively.

However, I don't think that what I wrote in my $2^{nd}$ paragraph (namely $H+K$) is allowed. We can only write $H+K$ if they are subgroups of a wider group $G$ and if three conditions are realized:

- $G = HK = \{hk | h\in H, k\in K \}$
- $H\cap K = \{ 1_{G} \}$
- $hk = kh$ for every $h\in H, k\in K $

So is my isomorphism $\phi$ enough or should I go and prove all three points to prove $H\times K$ is an internal direct product (made of $H$ and $K$) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "realized" here means you can somehow regard $H \times K$ as an internal direct product of some group. The point is where this internal direct product is. Let's say you are working over ambient group $G = H \times K$. This group $G$ needs not contain $H$ or $K$, but it contains a copy of $H$, namely $H' = H \times {e_K}$. Similarly $K'=e_H \times K$ is a copy of $K$. Then it can be checked that $H', K'$ satisfied three conditions you listed above, thus $H \times K$ can be thought as internal direct product of $H'K'$ in $G$.

Comment: Just one little follow-up question: does this has to do with normal subgroups ? I actually read before posting the question something about these copies of $H$ and $K$ but they were talking about normal groups (and I prefered ignoring it, because I don't know about normal groups..).

Comment: In the definition of the internal direct product, you need $H,K$ to be normal subgroup so that the notation $HK$ makes sense as a group and the three conditions you listed above hold. I think you should check the definition of normal subgroup again and verify $H',K'$ are normal subgroups this yourself